# writing c++ operator- overload?

Tags: c++

i was about to finish my assignment when i got a problem with operator- overloading, error says

Error   1   error C2661: 'Date::Date' : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments c:\users\86\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignmnent 3 840\assignmnent 3 840\date.cpp 137

2   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "Date::Date" matches the argument list c:\users\86\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\assignmnent 3 840\assignmnent 3 840\date.cpp  137

and its marking Date in return Date(mt,dy,yr); please help, i have been trying this thing for 3 hours already now.

here is the code

```
////////////////////date.h


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Date
{
private:
int day,month,year ;

public:

Date ();
void setValues();
//   int getValues() ;
Date operator=(const Date &);
//
Date(const Date &);
// 

//friend     Date operator+(Date a,Date b);
Date operator-(const Date &);


friend bool operator>(Date a, Date b);
friend bool operator==(Date a, Date b);
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Date a);
friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Date &a);




//



};

/////////////////date.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Date
{
private:
int day,month,year ;

public:

Date ();
void setValues();
//   int getValues() ;
Date operator=(const Date &);
//
Date(const Date &);
// 

//friend     Date operator+(Date a,Date b);
Date operator-(const Date &);


friend bool operator>(Date a, Date b);
friend bool operator==(Date a, Date b);
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Date a);
friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Date &a);




//



};

////////driver.cpp
//test.cpp
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Date date1;
Date date2 = date1; //copy constructor called

cout << "Initial date values\n";
cout << "Date 1 is ";
cout << date1 << endl;
cout << "Date 2 is ";
cout << date2 << endl;
cout << "Enter a date no earlier than 1800\n";
cin >> date1;




cout << "Enter another date no earlier than 1800\n";
cin >> date2;
cout << "Revised date values\n";
cout << "Date 1 is ";
cout << date1 << endl;
cout << "Date 2 is ";
cout << date2 << endl;

if (date1 == date2)
cout << "The two input dates are the same\n";
else if (date1 > date2)

{
cout << "Date 1 is later in time than Date 2 by ";
Date temp = date1 - date2;
cout << temp << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "Date 2 is later in time than Date 1 by ";
Date temp = date2 - date1;
cout << temp << endl;
}



//Date date3, date4;
//date4 = date3 = date2; //overloaded assignment operator called
//cout << "After the assignment date4 = date3 = date2\n";
//cout << " Date 3 is " << date3 << " and Date 4 is " << date4 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the call site? the line in which you're actually calling the operator?

Answer (score 2):

In the `.cpp` file, you're not supposed to redefine the class, but include the header and implement the methods. So, `Date.h` is ok, but `Date.cpp` should be something along the lines of:

```
//Date.cpp
#include "Date.h"

Date::Date ()
{
}

void Date::setValues()
{
}
Date Date::operator=(const Date &)
{
   return *this;
}
Date::Date(const Date &)
{
}
Date Date::operator-(const Date &)
{
   return *this;
}
bool operator>(Date a, Date b)
{
    return true;
}
bool operator==(Date a, Date b)
{
    return true;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Date a)
{
    return out;
}
istream &operator>>(istream &in, Date &a)
{
    return in;
}
```

The implementations are missing, the operators should be declared in another header, possibly `Date.h`, and `operator =` should return a `Date&`, not a `Date` (though not mandatory.

Also, if you're looking to call `Date` with 3 parameters, you probably want:

```
Date::Date (int day_, int month_, int year_ ) :
   day(day_), month(month_), year(_year)
{
}
```

in your implementation file, and also declare this constructor in the header.

Comment: I`m not sure what you mean if be hones, can you be more specific please, I am just starting all this programming stuff and still a noob :) thanks.

Comment: @user1335175 I was pretty specific. You're not supposed to redefine the class in the `.cpp` file, you have to implement the methods there.

Comment: Thank you i fixed my program by adding 3 parameter constructor :)

Comment: @user1335175 sure, please take the time to accept the answer if it was helpful.